# Is Informatica powercenter no longer available

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Is Informatica Powercenter no longer available as independent product? All I can see on their website is cloud, cloud and cloud.

Comment: have a talk to their sales team pls. i can see they have 10.5.1 documentation. i know client uses 10.2 version.

Comment: It is because existing people are aware something like on-premise version of Informatica exists. However, if somebody is new to informatica, he has no way of knowing from their website, that on-premise version also exists. Everyone packaging their product under cloud label, sad for industry.

Comment: cloud is easier, convenient. cheap so it may be good for product companies and business clients. Now, functionality wise, infa cloud is also good and provide pretty much everything a on prem can plus could capability. They have been pushing infa cloud for long time like this so you are not only one who is sad.

Comment: Looks like a question to Informatica sales representatives :) Did you try asking them? Make sure to update this with the reply you get!

Comment: Ahh, the sales people, if I ask them one question, they will ask me 100 questions and try to sell "cloud packaged products" which I am not interested in at the moment.